# extract data from twitter

Tags: groovy, nlp, weka, sentiment-analysis, rapidminer

I want to extract tweets at real time, I'm using RapidmMiner to do the sentiment analysis and in order to gather data I prefer to use a tool to extract them automatically from twitter, I think that groovy with json using weka can accomplish this task but I didn't find a tuto to do that  , is there other simple tools to ?

Answer (score 1):

[HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/home.html) is cool. I used it a lot to test webservices. It also has some [twitter examples](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/post.html).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out [sentiment140](http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students) you can download their corpus which is already tagged for sentiment. It is a really great place to start.

The authors of sentiment140 used the MaxEnt classifier. The code isn't open source but you can use their work as a starting off point.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout "The archivist", a desktop tool to search and save tweets. It can export at maximum 1500 tweet in .txt or .xls file. I'm actually using the paid version (9.99$) that allow you to save 2000 tweets in a .json file, that is more rich than the others.